# Xcode 7 beta 5 halts at building for iOS/Watchapp at 2 out of 2 Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7-beta5

Hi I am using the latest beta of Xcode7 (I have no choice) and I am building a native watch app and iOS project and it appears that it will not complete the build process it is stuck at storyboard 2 of 2.

I am using Yosemite latest build. I checked the release notes and the board and there is nothing coming up on this issue.

I have also tried just building an empty project the result is the same.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to say what you have tried, what ideas you have, and any other possible evidence.  Also try making a blank project and building it to see if the issue is w/ your project or w/ XCode.

Comment: Sorry let me edit that